# ARM hard fault on runtime function call in simulator

Tags: c, arm, simulator, bare-metal, newlib

I'm trying to build and run some project from 3rd party sources for bare-metal(no OS)ARM Cortex M3.

I build it with arm-none-eabi-gcc(success) with newlib.

I run it under simulator of TI Code Composer Studio.

**The problem:**

**When I run it, it fails into hard fault (entering into corresponding ISR) on the first call to the runtime library function**

Till now I sow it failing on calls to memmove or memcpy.
When tracing the disassembly I see that it fails exactly on the instruction

> BLX memset

**The question:
What can cause the fault and how to debug it ???**

Comment: Are you using both ARM and Thumb?   'BLX label' calls the label, (using link register for return address), and changes to Thumb mode.  Are you linking with the correct version of the library?

Comment: These are good questions. I compile with the following options: -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb. And for the linker - I don't specify any options regarding the library, how can I know/check that the library is ok ?

Comment: there are usually ARM and Thumb versions of the library.  I do not know your build system, so I don't know the correct options.  ARM/Thumb interop is a bit 'hairy', expecially with interrupt-handlers that must run in ARM mode.  It's just very suspicious that the fail occurs on a branch that causes a switch to Thumb mode - maybe it's then prefetching an illegal ARM instruction, something like that?

Comment: You're totally right, I found the problem and fixed it. If you could place your comment as an answer I would accept it. I just forgot to specify for linker the -mcpu as I did for the compiler. Now it's ok and the instruction is BL now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using both ARM and Thumb? 'BLX label' calls the label, (using link register for return address), and changes to Thumb mode. Are you linking with the correct version of the library?